# Are there Blu-ray differences for Dragon Maid?

Tags: miss-kobayashis-dragon-maid

Some series have Blu-ray differences such as animation improvements or minor adjustments.

Are there any differences with Miss Kobayashi's Dragon Maid? If so, any visual examples?

Comment: If anything, I failed to find Japanese resources that explained the differences between the BD and the TV version (or my search query suck), so it might be too uninteresting to be shared with the public. Meanwhile, I found a recent discussion in English about this on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/DragonMaid/comments/oig1k8/are_there_bluray_differences/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3).

Comment: @AkiTanaka Yes, funny enough that was my Reddit post. Alas, no answer there.